# symfony validator error name constant

Tags: symfony, validation

I was wondering what is the usage of these codes that are in each validator, i.e. in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotBlank.php#L24

```
class NotBlank extends Constraint
{
    const IS_BLANK_ERROR = 'c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3';
```

I could not find any documentation about it, neither in http://symfony.com/doc/master/validation/custom_constraint.html: what algorithm is used to generate them?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a UUID. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number used to
> identify information in computer systems. The term globally unique
> identifier (GUID) is also used.
>
> When generated according to the standard methods, UUIDs are for
> practical purposes unique, without depending for their uniqueness on a
> central registration authority or coordination between the parties
> generating them, unlike most other numbering schemes. While the
> probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is close
> enough to zero to be negligible.

In PHP you can generate it using [UUID](https://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) PECL package or using a library like [this one](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid).